# SQL Query to return the sum of balances from 1 or more rows from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My first post on stackoverflow - I hope you can assist this newbie please!

I have a requirement to return the sum of Leave Balances from 1 or more rows in the same table in SQL Server 2012. The result set must be grouped by EmployeeID and BalanceStartDate. There are instances where an employee has multiple LeaveType's, and there are instances where employees only has one leave type.

If only one LeaveType exists for the BalanceStartDate and Employee, then return the LeaveBalance. If multiple exist, sum the LeaveBalance across the LeaveType and return 1 result.

My source data on the table is as follows:

```
EmployeeID    BalanceStartDate    LeaveCategory    LeaveType    LeaveBalance
----------    ----------------    -------------    ---------    ------------
1             01-JAN-2016         ANNUAL           MANDATORY    2
1             01-JAN-2016         ANNUAL           NON-MAN      3
1             01-JAN-2015         ANNUAL           MANDATORY    5
1             01-JAN-2015         ANNUAL           NON-MAN      2
2             01-JAN-2016         ANNUAL           MANDATORY    6
2             01-JAN-2015         ANNUAL           MANDATORY    3
2             01-JAN-2014         ANNUAL           MANDATORY    1
2             01-JAN-2014         ANNUAL           NON-MAN      1
```

My expected result set is:

```
EmployeeID    BalanceStartDate    LeaveCategory    Sum
----------    ----------------    -------------    ---
1             01-JAN-2016         ANNUAL           5
1             01-JAN-2015         ANNUAL           7
2             01-JAN-2016         ANNUAL           6
2             01-JAN-2015         ANNUAL           3
2             01-JAN-2014         ANNUAL           2
```

So for each "year", we should have a unique row summing up the balance across the LeaveTypes (if more than one exists). If there is only 1 LeaveType, then only return the Leave Balance.

I wrote the following (which is almost there), but it is excluding rows where only 1 LeaveType exists, and is still returning 2 rows for a single year:

```
select A.LeaveBalance + B.LeaveBalance as 'Sum', A.EmployeeID
From
Table A
Inner Join Table B On A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID 
AND A.LeaveCategory = 'ANNUAL'
AND A.LeaveCategory = B.LeaveCategory 
AND A.BalanceStartDate = '01-JAN-2016'
AND A.BalanceStartDate = B.BalanceStartDate 
AND A.EmployeeID = '12345' 
AND A.LeaveType <> B.LeaveType
```

I hope this is enough Info?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Please excuse my newbie code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  
    EMPLOYEEID  
    ,BALANCESTARTDATE  
    ,LEAVECATEGORY  
    ,SUM( LEAVEBALANCE ) as sum  
from  
    EMPLOYEES  
group by  
    EMPLOYEEID  
    ,BALANCESTARTDATE  
    ,LEAVECATEGORY  
order by  
    EMPLOYEEID  
   ,BALANCESTARTDATE desc;
```

It will give result as you expected.

Comment: Thank you - exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SUM function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).

Try this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, BalanceStartDate, LeaveCategory, LeaveType, SUM(LeaveBalance) As SumOfLeaves
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY EmployeeID, BalanceStartDate, LeaveCategory, LeaveType
```

Comment: Thank you - I excluded the LeaveType and got the results I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
    A.EmployeeID,
    A.LeaveCategory,
    A.BalanceStartDate,
    SUM(A.LeaveBalance) AS TotalLeave
FROM
Table A
WHERE A.LeaveCategory = 'ANNUAL'
AND A.EmployeeID = '12345' 
GROUP BY
    A.EmployeeID,
    A.LeaveCategory,
    A.BalanceStartDate
```